# Select if exists else select 0 Does it query twice?

Tags: sql

I am doing a password authentication query like this.

```
if exists(select UserID from users where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password) 
    select UserID from users where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password
else 
    select 0
```

but it seems to me that I am querying twice for a single result
Can I just do this

```
Select UserID Where Username = @UserName and Password = @Password
```

and when I get my results just check the reader for number of results?

```
if (!myReader.HasRows)
    MessageBox.Show("UserName not found or Password invalid");
else
    //do login stuff
```

Guess what I am asking is, which of these is better, or are they the same?

Comment: Standard warning about storing reconstructable passwords in database applies.

Comment: @Quassnoi would you mind explaining this so called standard warning?

Comment: I researched it myself I think this is a good link to what Quassnoi was talking about, if you are reading this and wondering please check it out, it is not a big read but it is an excellent article  http://firelitdesign.blogspot.ca/2011/02/storing-passwords-in-databases.html

Comment: Storing passwords in the database in plain text or any other index-searchable condition is considered insecure. Your query suggests that it's possible to construct the value stored in the database solely from the value transmitted over the network. If your database leaks it is a security risk for every user. Store salted hashed values instead.

Comment: Thanks for that, I never knew this was a concern.  Damn noob!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT  ISNULL
        (
        (
        SELECT  userId
        FROM    users
        WHERE   userName = @userName
                AND password = @password
        ),
        0
        )
```

Your solution with checking number of records would work too of course.

Note that it will always return exactly one record and will fail if `userName` is not unique and there are duplicates of `@userName`.

As noted by @Andriy M, `COALESCE` will not help here since it's being internally rewritten into a `CASE` prone to the same problem.

Answering your question: yes, the original batch would access `users` twice.

Comment: I definitely like that better than mu first one.  I had to read on it, but it selects the first option with non null data, so if the first select doesn't work it moves on to the next. which in this case is a constant and will always work.  This is perfect thank you very much.

Comment: With scalar subqueries, it's [more preferable to use `ISNULL`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx) instead of `COALESCE` (because with `COALESCE` the subquery would be executed twice, which doesn't solve the OP's issue).

Comment: @AndriyM: It's a single subquery here which goes first in the list. It will be executed exactly once.

Comment: It doesn't take much time to verify. Try this and compare the plans for the two SELECTs: `DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int, Value int); SELECT COALESCE((SELECT Value FROM @t WHERE ID = 1), 0); SELECT ISNULL((SELECT Value FROM @t WHERE ID = 1), 0);`. They were different for me (on SQL Server 2008 R2).

Comment: @AndriyM: you're right, sorry for disparaging. Judging on the `IsFalseOrNull` in the leftmost nested loops, `COALESCE` is most probably being rewritten to a `CASE` on parsing stage.

Comment: It's all right. Yes, that's basically along the lines of what I've heard too, only I wouldn't be able to express it with so many clever words as you did. :)